# can I use *ngFor twice in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[image]

I'm fetching some data and displaying it in a table with `*ngFor` However I also have an array that I need to loop through and display it in the same table but I can't use `*ngFor` again for this new array because then they loop over each other too.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let update of updates">
  <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.currentPrice }}</td>
    <td> {{ update }} </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried that but doesn't work. I tried `*ngFor="let product of products, let update of updates"` also but doesn't work either.

Some extra info: updates is a converted version of a timeStamp. The JSON I'm fetching has a millisecond timestamp so I'm converting it to normal date and trying to display it back in the table.

[image: one is with the update and the other one with the products working well]

This is my JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ao4vx

And the update array:

```
update=["17-6-2019 18:25:49", "17-6-2019 18:26:23", "17-6-2019 18:26:43", "17-6-2019 18:27:05", "17-6-2019 18:27:24"]
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and how the resulting table should look like? It's really unclear to me what you mean by "displaying two arrays in the same table". Just `let updateOrProduct of updates.concat(products)`?

Comment: Some JSON samples or how your data structure looks like would help us to help you. Also if `updates` and `products` are variables it would be good to see how they are assigned

Comment: I added my JSON and the update array. They are both supposed to be displayed in the same table but I just cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Jojo i assume that products.length === updates.length

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you want a double for loop. Assuming from your graphs that products and updates have equal length...

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let update of updates; let i = index"> 
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td>{{ products[i].id }}</td>
                 <td>{{ products[i].name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ products[i].currentPrice }}</td>
                 <td> {{ update }} </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</ng-container>
```